# Nginx with Oracle

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oracle, nginx

I'm having the following problem, configured my [nginx](/questions/tagged/nginx) with gem passenger for my [ruby-on-rails](/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails) application using Oracle database (instant client), the principle is configured everything correctly, but when I access the address of my server, the following error occurs:

```
ERROR: ActiveRecord oracle_enhanced adapter could not load ruby-oci8 library. Please install ruby-oci8 gem. (LoadError)
.
.
.
```

My **gem ruby-oci8** is installed, when I run on rails server, it works normally.

My gemfile:

```
gem 'rails', '3.2.15'
gem 'ruby-oci8', '~> 2.1.0'
gem 'activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter', '~> 1.4.0'
```

On **Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6**

Any tips?

Comment: Do you use passenger? Can you show your Gemfile too?

Comment: Do you mean running `bundle exec rails s -e production` is completely OK? And you still didn't specify how you deploy to nginx.

Comment: Yes, in this case it works, the problem is in nginx. I'm using the gem passenger, you need the settings of it to help me?

Comment: I've added Apache config to my answer, if it helps you.

Comment: but in your case, you would use the apache server and not the nginx, I would not miss in performance?

Comment: Yeah, we used apache back then, but I think it's easily translates into Nginx config file.

Answer (score 0):

I found an old server with configuration close to yours:

```
gem 'rails', '~> 3.2.0'
gem 'ruby-oci8', '~> 2.1.0'
gem 'activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter', '~> 1.4.0'
```

It's Ubuntu 12.04, Apache, and Passenger.

Virtual host config looks like this:

```
LoadModule passenger_module /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-4.0.33/buildout/apache2/mod_passenger.so
PassengerRoot /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-4.0.33
PassengerDefaultRuby /usr/local/bin/ruby

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /...path.../public
    <Directory /...path.../public>
        Allow from all
        Options -MultiViews
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I edited my question with some more information. Thank you.